# With Pandas, how do I subtract all recurring elements of a series with an element of another series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, subtraction

I have a dataframe of this type:

```
    arr_time dep_time station
0   19:20:00 19:20:00 a
1   19:38:00 19:45:00 b
2   18:55:00 19:00:00 a
3   19:40:00 19:45:00 a
4   19:50:00 19:55:00 b 
.
.
```

What I need to do is:
for every same item in *station*, subtract related items in *dep_time* with every single related item in *arr_time* (not considering the same item). For example:
for *station* **a**:

```
 for i in range(len(arr_time)):
      for j in range(len(dep_time)):
         if i != j:
            dep_time[j] - arr_time[i]
```

Result, for *station* **a**, must be:

```
result
-00:20:00
00:25:00
```

and so on, for all stations in *station*.
Need to write this with Pandas, due to the large amount of data. I will be very thankful to whoever can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  I used `pd.merge` to link every station 'a' to every other station 'a' (etc.).  Then I filtered so we won't compare a station to itself, and performed the time arithmetic.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''    arr_time dep_time station
0   19:20:00 19:20:00 a
1   19:38:00 19:45:00 b
2   18:55:00 19:00:00 a
3   19:40:00 19:45:00 a
4   19:50:00 19:55:00 b 
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

# create unique identifier for each row
df['id'] = df.reset_index().groupby('station')['index'].rank(method='first').astype(int)

# SQL-style self-join: all station 1's; all station 2's, etc.
t = pd.merge(left=df, right=df, how='inner', on='station', suffixes=('_l', '_r'))

# don't compare station to itself
t = t[ t['id_l'] != t['id_r'] ] 

# compute elapsed time (as timedelta object)
t['elapsed'] = pd.to_timedelta(t['dep_time_l']) - pd.to_timedelta(t['arr_time_r'])

# convert elapsed time to minutes (may not be necessary)
t['elapsed'] = t['elapsed'] / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1) # convert to minutes

# create display
t = (t[['station', 'elapsed', 'id_l', 'id_r']]
     .sort_values(['station', 'id_l', 'id_r']))
print(t)

   station  elapsed  id_l  id_r
1        a     25.0     1     2
2        a    -20.0     1     3
3        a    -20.0     2     1
5        a    -40.0     2     3
6        a     25.0     3     1
7        a     50.0     3     2
10       b     -5.0     1     2
11       b     17.0     2     1
```